# Uploading an empty file to S3 with Java

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Getting error when I try to stream empty data into S3.
Below is the error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception:
>   The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema 
>   (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedXML; Request ID: BC194D061F65DC3B), S3 Extended Request ID: RjC6LY05Gj93iQTWAdjL/JcQBrl/NzMt749DOwpVsTJ2YN63A0EQmFWaBXxwHzBo+/a8A3MoP70=

Is there a way to create an empty file in S3 via a Java SDK output stream?

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely!  With the assumption that you're performing a multipart (per best practices), you'll want to carve out a special case for zero-byte files:

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = /* your S3 client builder technique */
if ( contentLength == 0 ) {
  s3Client.putObject( bucketName, targetKeyName, 
        new FileInputStream( file ), objectMetadata );
} else {
  // Do your multipart upload per usual
}
```

Multipart uploads throw an MalformedXML exception when zero parts are requested, but it doesn't explicitly call this out in the message.  It's also possible that another portion of your request is malformed as well, such as if the ObjectMetadata is corrupted, though usually you'll get a clearer exception message in those cases.